# WPF How to raise the mouse event on two UIElement overlaid to each other

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, code-behind

I have two UIElements. An Image inside a ViewBox and Canvas that overlays it. On both is registered MoseMove event in the code behind.
Currently is raised the event only on the element that is on the top.

Is there any way how to raise MouseMove on both UIElements?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
        <Viewbox Name="border" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" Panel.ZIndex="0" >
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="image"  Panel.ZIndex="1"  >
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="d:\test.png"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
        <Canvas Name="canvas" Panel.ZIndex="2" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            border.PreviewMouseMove += Border_PreviewMouseMove;
            canvas.PreviewMouseMove += Canvas_PreviewMouseMove;
        }

        private void Border_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Not Raised...
        }

        private void Canvas_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Raised...
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :)

```
private void Canvas_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     border.RaiseEvent(e);
}
```